# How can I revoke a downvote?

Tags: support, downvotes, undo

I accidentally clicked upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/483821/1525840) and to remedy it, I accidentally clicked downvote. When I realized the mistake, it was too late to revote.

How can I correct the mistake?

Please note that it's been more than two hours since the vote, hence I'm unable clicking the button again to cancel it.

Comment: Create an alt account and wote up. :P

Comment: @Deduplicator That's not a duplicate at all. In my case, I **knew** how to cancel my vote. It's just been more than two hours so I wasn't allowed. In the post you incorrectly linked to, the user doesn't know that clicking upvote again will cancel the previously cast vote. In my view, totally different matters. But you're right - googling the words only brings that answer. I've seen it myself.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Yes, I know you understood how that normally works. But in both your and his case, that method wouldn't have worked anymore, and the answer tells what to do. So, it's the same question.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not sure where the other answer says that one might edit the question and then revote. The reply below, though, does. I'm all in for marking duplicates but in this case, I feel you were a bit too eager. Having said that, perhaps it's not so meaningful to invest more time into this matter. There are more significant tasks to pursue.

Comment: The end of the second and last sentence.

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh, so you've got no significant tasks... (meant as a friendly joke, not a rant, just to be clear) Well, I have to admit that I stand corrected. It **does indeed** answer my question. For some reason, it doesn't feel so but it might be my English or my interpretation of the phrasing. At any rate, it's highly subjective, so I readily admit that you were correct. I'll even vote for dupiness of this one myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vote reversal limitation is removed when the post is edited, so you have three options:

- If you can improve upon the post, edit it.
- Wait for someone else to edit the post.
- Just move on.

There is no other way to bypass the voting limitation, so if you don't want to edit the post and don't want to wait around for someone else to edit the post then you're stuck with the "just move on" option. In the larger scheme of things one downvote doesn't matter.

Comment: Or wait for *someone else* to make an edit.